# Spring cloud task junit test case which uses hsql db is failing

Tags: spring, junit, spring-cloud-task

I have spring boot application with `@EnableTask` which is working fine.

I have a test case which uses hsql database as part of test case is failing with the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(
        ......
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'taskLifecycleListener'; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not increment identity; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: TASK_SEQ
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:50)
        ......
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
        ... 25 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not increment identity; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: TASK_SEQ
  .......
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:175)
        ... 37 more
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: TASK_SEQ
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.AbstractIdentityColumnMaxValueIncrementer.getNextKey(AbstractIdentityColumnMaxValueIncrementer.java:98)
        ... 44 more
    Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: TASK_SEQ
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableName(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readRangeVariableForDataChange(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserDML.compileInsertStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
        ... 53 more
```

Can somebody tell me what's going wrong? I've tried with spring.cloud.task.close_context_enable=false also but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Cloud Task is trying to create the Task Repository schema and doesn't have permissions to do so.  If you don't want to initialize the task schema, you can set the property `spring.cloud.task.initialize.enable=false`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I've set above property in test.properties still it is failing with the error `user lacks privilege or object not found: TASK_SEQ` .

Comment: Sorry, I missread.  That error means that the table isn't there in the first place.